# How to recovery Windows 7 MBR with only Lenovo recovery disk (without Windows 7 installation disk)

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr

I have a Lenovo T420 with Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium installed. I only have 4 recovery discs which is made when I got the laptop. There is no original Windows 7 installation disc.

Now I messed up the MBR and found people are suggesting using `bootrec` (boot recovery) on Windows 7 installation disc to fix the MBR. I've borrowed a Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate DVD and try using it. But I got the error message:

> The version of system recovery options is not compatible with the
>   version of windows you are trying to repair try using a recovery disc
>   that is compatible with this version of windows.

And looks like my original recovery disc can only perform a factory recovery. So how can I fix the Windows 7 MBR in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the diagnosis, found that there are 3 partitions on the drive:

1. SYSTEM_DRV (1GB) active
2. OS (100GB)
3. Lenovo_Recovery (15GB)

Where I should set OS partition to active, not SYSYEM_DRV. This fixed the issue.

I also found that EasyBCD can help to diagnose or repair the bootloader.

Comment: Make a system repair disc, go to the All Programs menu and look in the Maintenance folder for "Create a System Repair Disc" Might comer in handy at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after "ghosting" a ThinkCentre M91p.
I just saw a blinking cursor...

1. Download or make a Windows 7 Recovery Disk (64 Bits in my case).
   (32Bits Recovery Disk doesn't works with 64 Bits OS and vice versa ! even if you just need to access to the command line)
2. `bootrec.exe /FixMbr`
3. `bootrec.exe /FixBoot`
4. `bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`
5. It doesn't detect my OS Partition so I had to execute:

   ```
   bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
   c:
   cd boot
   attrib bcd -s -h -r
   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
   ```
6. `bootrec /RebuildBcd`

Windows restart correctly but the recovery button (F11) doesn't works...

If someone has managed to ghost a Thinkcentre M91p with all partitions (BOOT + OS + RECOVERY) please tell us how you did it!